# How to use Canon 430EX II as a slave for Rebel T1i?

Tags: canon, off-camera-flash, canon-500d

I have been trying to figure out how to set my camera/flash to slave mode.  Can I use my Canon 430EX II as an off camera flash with my Rebel T1i?  If so, how would I accomplish this?

Comment: Do you mean wirelessly, or with cables? Also, do you want TTL automatic flash exposure control or do you want a manual "dumb slave"?

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, your camera does not offer built-in wireless control of your flash. In order to control your flash off camera, you need to purchase the [Canon ST-E2](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/164264-REG/Canon_2478A002_ST_E2_Speedlite_Transmitter.html).

At this date, only the Canon 7D, 60D and 600D (Rebel T3i / Kiss X5) offer built-in wireless control of flash, but I assume that will change over time.

There are solutions from [PocketWizard](http://www.pocketwizard.com/products/transmitter_receiver/flextt5-canon/), and [Radio Poppers](http://radiopopper.com/) that also support E-TTL remote, off camera flash support, but they tend to be a bit more expensive, but a great alternative if you have a challenging environment or shoot (around corners, long distance)

If you wish to remotely manually fire your flash (meaning not use E-TTL), you can get the '[Cactus](http://www.gadgetinfinity.com/cactus-4-channel-wireless-flash-trigger-set-v2s.html)' or 'eBay' triggers, that will allow remote firing of flash, but will not support the in-camera settings and control.

Comment: Doesn't the 60D offer flash controller as well?

Comment: Good catch, forgot about the 60D

Comment: I think the 600D does too

Comment: I think the 650D (T4i) does also.